# dropping characters when passing json to webapi method

Tags: javascript, json, wcf-web-api

I'm attempting to pass a string to a web api method. The string on the client side looks like this: "shipment id :{{{shipmentId}}}", but at the server, the {{{shipmentId}}} is being dropped and the web api method on the server only sees "shipment id:". The triple brackets are there as a place holder so I can do a text replacement on the server during another process. So I'm trying to save the entire string with the triple brackets to the database. There are no errors, just don't get the full string. Is there someway I can pass that data a
long to the server?
This is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/api/emailtemplate/",
type: 'put',
data: ko.toJSON(self),
contentType: 'application/json',
success: function (result) { ...
```

I tried another series of characters instead of the triple brackets (< and >) with the same result. This is the request as seen from fiddler:
PUT http:///api/emailtemplate/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1704
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http:///Admin/Addons/EmailTemplate.aspx
Content-Length: 723
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=mbiwmduzvawbsbppl0cochoq; AuthCookieKey=0D3CC8F49283835A506743C6E7A86B887E89193290A0E9F33D574472ACA5DC3B94FF45B1FF905EE45FBC56807C8662564603C1832FD1A320A9EFF7155A3F298E5902D3E5D5796AA7DD31A459E84F52A717EDA0E5FF8EA1F82B1A9CC37A6D00F64ECF25AFF27331DF24DA54E76A7B5A8BA9A0679E8640289E8FFE16A0F3D3140EE6AECAF445297B879E9BA4B6213182A261DD863E4BEB2F53E40EAAE1EB9EEA5B
Connection: keep-alive

{"subject":"test 2 ","body":"shipment id : ","clientName":"localhost"}

Adding the escapes to the triple brackets didn't help.

Comment: you might need to escape the brackets then if you want them to come out as literal brackets in string format `"\{\{\{shipmentId\}\}\}"`

Comment: Can you show us the HTTP request (from network inspector)?